# Error adding abline to an xts plot when run within braces

Tags: r, xts

Sample code:

```
df_2=as.data.frame(c(1:10))
rownames(df_2)=Sys.Date()+c(1:10)
xts_2=as.xts(df_2)
vline=.index(xts_2)[4]

{
  png(filename = paste0(Sys.Date(),'-test',".png"), width = 800, height = 600)
  plot(xts_2[,1])
  print(dev.cur())
  abline(v=vline, col="red")
  dev.off()
}
```

If I select the lines from png...dev.off() and run, I get the desired output file.

However if I run the sequence with the braces selected (for example to run if a conditional is met), I get the error:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

The result of the print(dev.cur()) line in both cases is:

```
png 
  2
```

Answer (score 0):

The braces suppress auto-printing, similar to if the `plot()` call were in a `for` loop or a function.  You can work-around this by explicitly printing the plot.

```
{
  png(filename = paste0(Sys.Date(),'-test',".png"), width = 800, height = 600)
  print(plot(xts_2[,1]))
  print(dev.cur())
  abline(v=vline, col="red")
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solves the issue for me.  In debugging this problem, I did notice some quirky behavior:  if I plot xts_2 (stored as a data frame) I do not get the error, but if I plot xts_2 (as defined above), I do get the error.

Comment: @rsoto74: that's because calling `plot()` on a data.frame dispatches to `plot.default()`, not `plot.xts()`.  `plot.default()` doesn't require explicit printing (like ggplot2, lattice, etc) when auto-printing is disabled.